# Wordpress get_post_meta not working

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I'm trying to add some custom fields in wordpress and I'm facing a problem. I have 4 different fields (rooms, persons, bathrooms, surface) and the code I'm using is the bellow, the problem is that only the value from the first field is displayed, for the the other three I just get the title (ex. Rooms: 10, Persons:  , Bathrooms:  , Surface:  ,). Can you please tell what am I doing wrong? 
Thank you all in advance.

```
    <?php if ($accommodation_location != null) { ?>
    <div class="price">
    <?php _e('Rooms: ', 'bookyourtravel'); ?> <?php global $wp_query; $postid = $wp_query->post->ID; echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'accommodation_max_rooms', true); wp_reset_query(); ?>
   <br/><?php _e('Persons: ', 'bookyourtravel'); ?> <?php global $wp_query; $postid = $wp_query->post->ID; echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'accommodation_max_person_count', true); wp_reset_query(); ?>
   <br/><?php _e('Bathrooms: ', 'bookyourtravel'); ?> <?php global $wp_query; $postid = $wp_query->post->ID; echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'accommodation_max_bathrooms', true); wp_reset_query(); ?>
   <br/><?php _e('Surfase: ', 'bookyourtravel'); ?> <?php global $wp_query; $postid = $wp_query->post->ID; echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'accommodation_max_sqmtot', true); wp_reset_query(); ?> <?php _e('m2', 'bookyourtravel'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the solution by my self. I'm posting it in case anyone in the future will need it!

```
<?php if ($accommodation_location != null) { ?>
<div>
    <?php _e('Rooms: ', 'bookyourtravel'); ?><?php echo $accommodation_obj->get_custom_field('max_rooms'); ?>
       <br/><?php _e('Persons: ', 'bookyourtravel'); ?><?php echo $accommodation_obj->get_custom_field('max_person_count'); ?>
       <br/><?php _e('Bathrooms: ', 'bookyourtravel'); ?><?php echo $accommodation_obj->get_custom_field('max_bathrooms'); ?>
       <br/><?php _e('Surfase: ', 'bookyourtravel'); ?><?php echo $accommodation_obj->get_custom_field('max_sqmtot'); ?><?php _e('m2', 'bookyourtravel'); ?>
</div>
```